# Pass php array values as JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP array like this.

```
Array
(   
  [0] => hal([[br,1],[cl,4]])
  [1] => alk([[nc(1),1,2],[nc(1),3]])
)
```

How to pass to JavaScript like below.

```
var hal=[["br",1],[cl,4]];
var alk=[[nc(1),1,2],[nc(1),3]];
```

I write some code

```
<script>
  var data = <?=json_encode($input);?>;    //$input is name of the php array
  var hal=[data[0].substring(5,data[0].lastIndexOf(']'))];
  var alk=[data[1].substring(5,data[1].lastIndexOf(']'))];
  document.write(hal[0]);
</script>
```

The output is [br,1],[cl,1] and my expected output is like the one below.Any ideas? Thank you.

```
document.write(hal[0]);  => ["br",1]
document.write(hal[0][0]); => ["br"]
```

Comment: "I have a php array like this" Is that just an array of strings? If they are, probably you can do this a better way, instead of building a string you should build data. If not, please update the question with valid array structure – try copying and pasting output of `print_r($input);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer for my problem.Here i pass value from php as string.Then that string convert it to an object.
`<?php`
`$input="hal([[br,1],[cl,4]])";`
`preg_match('@^([^[]+)?([^)]+)@i',$input, $hal); //get string as '[[br,1],[cl,4]]'`
`?>`
`<script>`
`var hal1 = <?=json_encode($hal[2]);?>; //'[[br,1,2],[cl,1,2]]' pass to javaScript`

`function toJSObject(str){`
 `str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '"$1"');`
 `return (JSON.parse(str))`
`}`
`var hal = toJSObject(hal1); // pass to JS object [['br',1,2],['cl',1,2]]`
`document.write(hal);`
`</script>`
And also get this as right.
`document.write(hal[0]);  => ["br",1]`
`document.write(hal[0][0]); => ["br"]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple variables, you'll want to loop through the array; you can grab the names [using a regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). If you're trying to turn this into valid data you can parse, like a JSON string, you're going to have to do an awful lot of work; likely wherever you're getting this string from would be a better place to look to. Have them pass you a valid JSON string instead.

```
<script>
<?php foreach($input as $v) {
    preg_match("/(\w+)\((.*)\)/", $v, $matches);
    $var = $matches[1];
    $val = str_replace("'", "\\'", $matches[2]);
    echo "var $var = '$val';\n";
} ?>
</script>
```

Comment: This is split value as inside the `()` brackets.and it is also give `[[br,1],[cl,4]]` as string format.but i want those as array format,only `br`,`cl` are strings numbers are integers.

Comment: Thank you for your idea.Using `preg_match` I can get my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [Transform PHP Vars to JavaScript](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer) by Jeffrey Way that you can use to transfer your variable easily to your Javascript.

First, create an implementation of the `Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\ViewBinder` interface. This class is in charge of inserting the given JavaScript into your view/page.

```
<?php

class MyAppViewBinder implements Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\ViewBinder {

    // $js will contain your JS-formatted variable initializations
    public function bind($js)
    {
        // Do what you need to do to add this JavaScript to
        // the appropriate place in your app.
    }
}
```

Next, put it all together:

```
$binder = new MyAppViewBinder;
$javascript = new PHPToJavaScriptTransformer($binder, 'window'); // change window to your desired namespace

$javascript->put(['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Now, you can access `window.foo` from your JavaScript.

Comment: I thing This way is bit difficult and long. I want a simple way to get result.

Comment: If you're not familiar with `interface` then you should go with @miken32. However, the way I've provided would be better once you've implemented it. So, anytime you want to pass data you can do like just `$javascript->put(['foo' => 'bar']);` and access it from the Javascript using `window.foo` like you always do. It's more clear and readable way in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer is ok. but I can find the simple way.Thanks again for your answer.